# What is a good hosted software for FAQ

Tags: wiki, cms

I need something in a form of Knowledge Base/FAQ/Wiki to deliver FAQ to users over web. Preferably hosted solution. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you are moderately comfortable coding in PHP, the best option is to just write yourself a quick application. It's fun and you also learn from doing this.

However, if you're already advanced and can't be bothered with such low-level nonsense or you can't code PHP at all then there are some good open-source alternatives for you such as [phpMyFAQ](http://www.phpmyfaq.de/) and [RTFM](http://bestpractical.com/rtfm/).

If you want something heavier, you can easily turn a CMS such as WordPress into a Knowledgebase Manager by using free plugins like [this](http://faq-tastic.com/faqtastic-lite-free/). Tutsplus also has [a tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-an-interactive-faq-with-wordpress-and-jquery-ui/) on how to do this yourself using custom posts.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this helps. A good solutions for me is to have an inexpensive web solution that is hosted by someone else. I don't want to go through pains of installing it/maintaining it.

Comment: In which case you might want to just host a flat file database-driven wiki on dropbox, something I have done in the past. Completely free hosting and fast too. [http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26515/build-your-own-personal-wiki-accessible-from-any-pc/] Of course, domain names won't work unless you do something like this: http://www.labnol.org/software/dropbox-with-custom-domain/18349/

Answer (score 1):

There are some great free CMS packages that can be customized to facilitate the type of site you are looking for.  The most popular free packages are

- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)
- [Drupal](http://www.drupal.com/)
- [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/)
- [Moodle](http://moodle.org/)

Out of the box Moodle is most focused on an education oriented site, so may require less customization than the others.

I personally recommend Drupal for maximum flexibility.

If you are unable or unwilling to setup hosting and configure one of these CMS's yourself, there are many web hosts that will charge reasonable rates to configure and host a CMS of your choice.

An even simpler alternative is the excellent hosted & integrated CMS called [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com/).  This requires almost no technical skills but can be extensively customized.

Comment: Thanks this helps. A good solutions for me is to have an inexpensive web solution that is hosted by someone else. I don't want to go through pains of installing it/maintaining it.

Comment: Sounds like Squarespace would suit you nicely.  No patches & updates, auto backup etc.  Indestructible hosting.