# Tool to generate faq page (html)

Tags: html, generator

I dont care if the software is in an exe or a website

I would like something that i can feed a bunch of questions and their answers and have it generate the links/question part at the top of the page. I likely will want to enter in code snippets so i'd need `<pre>` support. What can i use?

Maybe i can write the Q&A part in markdown, generate the html then use another tool to generate the top part with the questions and links. Feel free to suggest a chain of tools.

Comment: Similar: [What is a good hosted software for FAQ](http://superuser.com/questions/333583/what-is-a-good-hosted-software-for-faq)

Answer (score 0):

Using Markdown (or something like it) is a good idea. Then you just need a TOC. For example [Grutatxt](http://triptico.com/software/grutatxt.html) can convert to HTML or PDF with a TOC.

Alternatively, [AutoFAQ](http://novia.net/~pschleck/auto-faq/)?